# Images are not visible after hosting my website

Tags: html, css, web-hosting, vs-web-site-project

I recently uploaded my website on GoDaddy hosting server. Everything is fine but images are not visible on my website. Please help me how I can solve this problem.

I have checked the permissions but still, it's not working.

[image]

```css
body
{
    background-image: url(background.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to assist people in helping you. This may include more complete code examples or samples of your hosting directory structure to demonstrate how your images are stored.

Comment: Did you update the urls in your database?